# How to filter array values and Obtain Average

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am practising on mongoDB using the famous restaurant collection. I have a list of records like this one:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59a5211e107765480896f3e5"),
"address" : {
    "building" : "1007",
    "coord" : [
        -73.856077,
        40.848447
    ],
    "street" : "Morris Park Ave",
    "zipcode" : "10462"
},
"borough" : "Bronx",
"cuisine" : "Bakery",
"grades" : [
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2014-03-03T00:00:00Z"),
        "grade" : "A",
        "score" : 2
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2013-09-11T00:00:00Z"),
        "grade" : "A",
        "score" : 6
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2013-01-24T00:00:00Z"),
        "grade" : "A",
        "score" : 10
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2011-11-23T00:00:00Z"),
        "grade" : "A",
        "score" : 9
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2011-03-10T00:00:00Z"),
        "grade" : "B",
        "score" : 14
    }
],
"name" : "Morris Park Bake Shop",
"restaurant_id" : "30075445"
}
```

I want to calculate the average for grades.score, using only elements with grades.grade = 'A'. What I am doing is

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([{$unwind: '$grades'}, {$filter: {input: '$grades.grade', as: 'grade', cond: {'$$grade': 'A'}}}, {$group: {_id: '$name', 'avg': {'$avg': '$grades.score'}}}, {$sort: {'avg': 1}}])
```

what's wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator is not a separate pipeline stage. It just returns an array as a property. It's best used in this case directly in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) as an argument to [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/):

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
  { '$group': {
    '_id': '$name',
    'avg': {
      '$avg': {
        '$avg': {
          '$map': {
            'input': {
              '$filter': {
                'input': '$grades', 
                'as': 'grade',
                'cond': { '$eq': [ '$$grade.grade',  'A' ] }
              }
            },
            'as': 'grade',
            'in': '$$grade.score'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}, 
  { '$sort': { 'avg': 1 } }
])
```

Also applying [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to extract the `"score"` values only and feed them to [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/), which appears "twice", being once to create the "avg" value in the document, and secondly an an "average accumulator" for the grouping key.

For the data shown in the question, you get:

```
{
    "_id" : "Morris Park Bake Shop",
    "avg" : 6.75
}
```

Which is the average score from only those entries marked with grade "A".

---

<s>Interestingly this works fine in the single document, but If applied to the full dataset from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/primer-dataset/primer-dataset.json this is producing `null` values for obtaining any `$avg` that is not actually accumulating over more than one document.</s>

Simply adding the average value from the filtered array to the document works fine:

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "average": {
      "$avg": {
         "$map": { 
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$grades",
              "as": "g",
              "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$g.grade", "A" ]  }    
            }
          },
          "as": "g",
          "in": "$$g.score"
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

As does accumulating over more than one document. i.e for `"cuisine"`:

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
  { '$group': {
    '_id': '$cuisine',
    'avg': {
      '$avg': {
        '$avg': {
          '$map': {
            'input': {
              '$filter': {
                'input': '$grades', 
                'as': 'g',
                'cond': { '$eq': [ '$$g.grade',  'A' ] }
              }
            },
            'as': 'g',
            'in': '$$g.score'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}, 
  { '$sort': { 'avg': 1 } }
])
```

This is meant to work as originally stated and demonstrably does when the value being "grouped for" actually occurs in more than one document.

Sadly the only reliable method that can apply no matter how many documents are being grouped over is therefore still applying `$unwind`. Which really should not be necessary in modern releases:

Whilst this would work with consistent results:

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "grades.grade": "A" } },
  { "$unwind": "$grades" },
  { "$match": { "grades.grade": "A" } },
  { "$group": {
     "_id": "$name",
     "score": { "$avg": "$grades.score" } 
  }},
  { "$sort": { "score": -1 } }
])
```

The most optimal thing to do and actually comparing "apples with apples" is to pre-filter any "documents" for only those that can possibly have an array element that matches the criteria with a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) in the initial stage:

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
  { '$match': { 'grades.grade': 'A' } },
  { '$group': {
    '_id': '$name',
    'value': {
      '$avg': {
        '$avg': {
          '$map': {
            'input': {
              '$filter': {
                'input': '$grades', 
                'as': 'g',
                'cond': { '$eq': [ '$$g.grade',  'A' ] }
              }
            },
            'as': 'g',
            'in': '$$g.score'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "value": -1 } }
])
```

Also the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) would be typically applied in the "negative" or "descending" order, indicating the largest values first. Or at least that makes the most sense when you are inspecting data and coming to grips with aggregation in general.

So looking shorter or possibly "less confusing" does not mean **"better"** here. The reason why we write this with the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operations within the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline is because processing with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is extremely costly.

Using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) creates a copy of the whole document for each array member, and this generally amounts to a massive increase in the number of documents to process, which of course adds considerable time to processing.

So the real case of "shorter is better" is actually in the usage of "less pipeline stages" and by not inflating the number of documents to process by removing all usage of [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) altogether.

The reason for adding in a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) before the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is because in the other example, when you process with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) any empty arrays would be removed from the documents to process, and then the other subsequent [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) there would filter out anything where there was no `"A"` grade and documents that did have grades but none that matched `"A"` would have also been removed there.

So using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), these documents would return `null` since that is the returned value from an empty array of arguments to [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/). But of course if the initial condition is that the "document" must contain the matching conditions, then initially empty or "filtered empty" arrays would never be considered since they were removed from processing at the very beginning.

Being that the golden rule of any aggregation operation that includes some degree of "filtering" is to **always** [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) as the very first pipeline stage, so that only documents that would be valid for any later conditions are the only ones selected. This also speeds things up considerably on it's own.

> **NOTE**: This caused me some considerable panic in a tired state because of the `null` values returned. It should be noted that the "usual" application of any `$group` operation is typically to accumulate and "reduce" results considerably.
>
> The `"$name"` field chosen in the question is pretty much unique for each document in the [sample dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/primer-dataset/primer-dataset.json) obtained from the MongoDB documentation samples. A more realistic "grouping" sample would be to use `"$cuisine"` from the data, which actually accumulates "across documents" for which you typically use

Comment: ok I think I got the theory, but when executing this I get this error: exception: invalid operator '$avg'

Comment: @user3174311 If you got the data from where I think you did then all you need to do is copy and paste. Noting the data source, I was actually just doing some investigation because I noticed some strange behavior. Added notes into the answer about this

Comment: actually in your last example the syntax is even more clear, thank you.

Comment: @user3174311 You really should come back and look. Despite my initial panic in a tired state, everything works properly as designed. You might find processing with `$unwind` easier to comprehend, but it really is not what you should be doing. So the answer expands on exactly "why" you should not be using `$unwind`, and what you really should be doing in learning how to do these things.